# Why does tomcat return error HTTP500?

Tags: java, tomcat, wicket

I created my own Session, subclasing `WebSession`. In the Tomcat console I can see an exception is being thrown:

```
pqlrd.is.seguridad.SesionPQLRD cannot be cast to org.apache.wicket.Session
```

My Extended WebSession:

```
package pqlrd.is.seguridad;

import org.apache.wicket.Session;
import org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WebSession;
import org.apache.wicket.request.Request;

import pqlrd.domain.AccesoWeb;
import pqlrd.domain.Usuario;

public final class SesionPQLRD extends WebSession {

public SesionPQLRD(Request request) {
    super(request);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

private AccesoWeb acceso;

public AccesoWeb getUsuario() {
    return acceso;
}

public void setUsuario(AccesoWeb usuario) {
    this.acceso = usuario;
}

public static SesionPQLRD getSesionPQLRD(){

    return (SesionPQLRD) Session.get();
}


public boolean estaLogeado(){
    return (acceso!=null);
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just because a `SessionPQLRD` is-a `WebSession` (hence `Session`) doesn't mean a `WebSession` is-a `SessionPQLRD`. You're trying to force a `WebSession` to be a `SesionPQLRD`, but unless Wicket knows to use your custom session instead of its own, it's going to return the framework default.

In a nutshell, you can't force a superclass to act like a subclass unless it can actually fulfill the contract of the subclass. Consider an `Animal` interface, a `ZooAnimal` implementation, and a `Zebra` subclass. A `ZooAnimal` might not be a `Zebra`, it could be a `Giraffe` instead.

Comment: I though this could help.But it isnt.
@Override
 public Session newSession(Request request, Response response) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  //return super.newSession(request, response);
  return new SesionPQLRD(request);
 }

Comment: So, the wrong was code that this method returns SesionPQLRD instead of Session. I've change it and will try this. But in the example i studied says this is allowed because of java covariance. This is confusing.

 public static Session getSesionPQLRD(){

  
  return (SesionPQLRD) Session.get();
 }

Answer (score 1):

> pqlrd.is.seguridad.SesionPQLRD cannot be cast to org.apache.wicket.Session

This says that something is trying to cast one of your `SesionPQLRD` objects to `org.apache.wicket.Session`, and your class does not inherit or extend that class.  On the face of it this is nonsense.  According to the source code, your class is clearly a subclass of `WebSession`, and `WebSession` is a subclass of `Session`.  So what gives?

Well I think that the most likely explanation is that your Tomcat is loading two copies of the `Session` / `WebSession` classes using different class loaders.  And the most likely reason for that is that you have two webapps in the same container that are sharing objects.  If the webapps each have their own copies of the wicket JAR containing the `Session` and `WebSession` classes, then each will have their own version of those classes.  When one of your webapps tries to use an instances created by the other one, the types will be incompatible, and typecasts will fail.

There are two simple ways to avoid this:

- stop sharing objects between the two webapps, or
- remove the JAR files from the webapps' lib directories, and put them in the shared library directory.

Comment: Classloading issues are the most probable cause indeed. But instead of removing wicket's jars from the app's WEB-INF/lib, keep them there (each app with its own set of wicket jars), and remove any wicket jar from tomcat's lib (shared/lib, common/lib, depending of its version) folder. Tomcat will keep the classes' versions separated (although JBoss in some conditions won't). Or keep only the server version (as Stephen C described), but in this case be really sure there is no other version in any other folder or app.

Comment: @tetsuo - *"Tomcat will keep the classes' versions separated"*.  If that was the case, then this problem wouldn't occur at all.  I suspect that he's implement some channel behind the scenes that is allowing the webapps to share instances.  My suggestions are either 1) don't share the instances, or 2) put all relevant JARs into the shared lib dir.

Comment: This problem occurs when you put conflicting jars in common/lib and WEB-INF/lib. Tomcat structures its classloaders as a tree, in which applications' jars are leaves, protected from each other. But common/lib is the parent of webapp classloaders, thus shared among them. http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html

Comment: @tetsuo - I know all of that, and it doesn't directly matter.  Indeed, you *could* have conflicting JARs in different webapps ... so long as the different versions of the classes loaded by each webapp don't get together.  It is only when they get together that there are problems; e.g. when on webapp can get hold of *instances* of the other's version of the classes.  And indeed, when this happens, the JARs can have identical contents and you'd STILL have this problem.

Comment: yes, by 'conflicting jars' I meant jars containing classes with the same package/name, not necessarily with different contents. by any means, classes loaded by different classloaders are different classes, regardless of them being identical or not.

Comment: @tetsuo - how is that different to what I wrote in my answer and my comments?

Comment: I don't know, actually. My brain chose to ignore your first option, but even now re-reading it, it seems misleading to me. "stop sharing objects between the two webapps" may mean "keep the jars in each application, even if the same" (what I've suggested), but the more direct interpretation is to not share object instances between applications, which would be hard, if not impossible, to do without putting the jars into the shared folder. That said, I only commented your answer instead of providing a new one because yours is correct, it just needs some clarifications.

Comment: @tetsuo - by objects, I meant Java objects; i.e. instances of the classes that are different in the two webapps due to the fact that they are loaded by different classloaders.  The point is that the OP would have had to do something tricky to allow one webapp to access the other's objects.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you also override the newSession method in WicketApplication class. You need to specify to Wicket which session class it should use.

```
public class WicketApplication extends WebApplication {

   //...

   @Override
   public Session newSession(final Request request, final Response response) {
       return new SessionPQLRD(request);
   }
}
```